# Increment numbers in a string by one

Tags: python-3.x, regex

I have a 'annotation string' as below

```
an_str = r""" Excel file name: {0}
No.of Iterations: {1}
Cp = {2}
CpK = {3}
There are {4}ppm values below the lower tolerance limit
There are {5}ppm values above the upper tolerance limit
""".format(filename, iterations, cp, cpk, ppm_bl, ppm_ol)
```

As the scripts is evolving, new variables are being added to this string. New variable are always added at the start of the string. So, when a new variable is added, I want to increment all the existing numbers in the string by 1 (like below). I can do it manually but I was wondering if regex can be used to increment it automatically.

```
an_str = r""" Project: {0}
Excel file name: {1}
No.of Iterations: {2}
Cp = {3}
CpK = {4}
There are {5}ppm values below the lower tolerance limit
There are {6}ppm values above the upper tolerance limit
""".format(project,filename, iterations, cp, cpk, ppm_bl, ppm_ol)
```

I will add the test `Project: {0}` & `project` manually. I just want the rest of the numbers to be updated via a small code if possible since I expect this to happen several times.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may try using `re.sub` here with a callback function:

```py
an_str = r"""Excel file name: {0}
No.of Iterations: {1}
Cp = {2}
CpK = {3}
There are {4}ppm values below the lower tolerance limit
There are {5}ppm values above the upper tolerance limit
"""
an_str_out = re.sub(r'\{(\d+)\}', lambda m: '{' + str(int(m.group(1)) + 1) + '}', an_str)
print(an_str_out)
```

This prints:

```
Excel file name: {1}
No.of Iterations: {2}
Cp = {3}
CpK = {4}
There are {5}ppm values below the lower tolerance limit
There are {6}ppm values above the upper tolerance limit
```

The idea here is to match every occurrence of `{num}` using the pattern `\{(\d+)\}`, which capture the number in the first capture group.  Then, we pass this match to a lambda callback function, which casts to integer, increments, and then casts back to text for a replacement.

Comment: Thanks. It works. If  `m.group(1)` here the value of each match?

Comment: @moys `m.group(1)` is the first _capture_ group, which in this case would be the number inside `{...}`.  Then we cast to integer, add one, then cast back to string for the replacement.

Comment: So, regex finds the item, replaces it & then moves forward? I thought it first finds all the elements & then replaces all. So, I was trying to figure out how to get the first value then add 1 to it & then replace it in 1st position & so on.

Comment: @moys ... but this is precisely what my answer is doing.  It find `{num}` one at a time, then processes the value according to your logic, and moves on.